# Searching for a tut for making a listview like setting.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, settings

Im searching for a toturial that shows me how to make a listview like in settings.apk, with the icon but them let the items open other apps.

i found some tutorial on mkyong with mobile os but that is not exacly what i want.

but how do i make mu intent use the different list items now i have this

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import com.mkyong.android.adaptor.MobileArrayAdapter;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class ListMobileActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Android", "iOS",
            "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_mobile,
        //      R.id.label, MOBILE_OS));

        setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("eu.chainfire.cfroot.cwmmanager",
                               "eu.chainfire.cfroot.cwmmanager.MainActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and this opens the same app with every button i want to open different apps with the buttons

greetz gekko

Comment: Settings is (was) a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html but you can open apps if you do `startActivity(Intent)` from `onClickListener` of any list

Comment: oke but im searching for a tutorial or some one who can explain me the full thing

Comment: Which version of Setting? Ice-cream sandwich? HoneyComb?

Comment: gingerbread i want a listview with icons that opens other apps